# Derived status field on table?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

My client is a long term rental agency.
So we have

```
 Goods 
    pk modelId

 Stock
    pk stockId, fk modelId

 Rentals ( rented stock)
    pk rentalId fk stockId
```

In addition stock may take on other statuses such as being repaired etc and may have more than one status at once.

It will make my life easier to put a status field(s) on the stock table but ultimately it's derived data that I can infer from other tables.
An example is finding the total number of goods in stock ( not rented ) including the ones with 0 qty in stock.
Should I

- add rented, onRepair etc status fields to the stock table
- maintain a stock on hand field
- look it up every time?

  ps the stock and goods tables are separate as there is a more complex taxonomy than I have explained here for the types of the stock i.e. manufacturers etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the status or other attribute can be derived from other tables, the easier option to implement is to keep it as it is and "look it up every time". Your tables stay normalized. and you don't have to maintain any derived values with complex solutions like triggers, etc.

When do you have to think about the other option? When the above approach is becoming slow - even though you have optimized your queries. If you have to calculate the averages for example of stock prices over 10 years and for thousands of stocks and goods, the queries will not be fast enough to be calculated on the fly.

So, you can first add tables or fields with aggregate or other derived data that you need. You can used indexed views (most RDBMS have that feature) or additional tables for aggregate data - this can work nicely for data that can't change any more, example statistical data for stock prices from previous days/months/years. When a day/month/year ends, the calculations are done (once) and the tables are updated. Then, you can seacrh fast those tables for older data and the "active" tables for newer data.

Other options for more complex situations include triggers that maintain the derived values. I would use this as a last resource but I'm sure there are opposite views on this matter.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn' thought of using views.